# Output contents of iframe in a div

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to populate the id="review" tag in the html body with the contents of the iframe (using google as an example page). Instead of the contents of the iframe it returns this: [object HTMLDocument] . What am I doing wrong?

```
function googleReview()
{
    var iframeWindow = document.getElementById('google_window').contentDocument;
    document.getElementById("review").innerHTML=iframeWindow;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe width="300px" height="80px" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" name="google_window" id="google_window" src="http://google.com"></iframe>

<p id="review">Review Area</p>

<button type="button" onclick="googleReview()">Change Review</button>
```

Comment: Unless the iframe is in the same domain, I don't think you'll be able to access its content.

Comment: tried `iframeWindow.body.innerHTML`? Your variable should be named iframeDocument since you are retrieving the window.document of the iframe and not the window itself.

Comment: @Matt - It returns "undefined" when I do it from the same domain, so I must be doing something wrong. I believe you're right that cross domain restrictions exist in this type of case.

Comment: For the same domain, something like `document.getElementById("review").innerHTML=iframeWindow.body.innerHTML;` should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that; when I add `iframeWindow.innerHTML` to get the contents I get a permission denied error. The issue is you're trying to access [cross origin (domain) information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).